# Not able to see base64 image in PDF using xslfo and FOP 2.1

Tags: image, pdf, base64, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a use case where I have to show an dynamic image on pdf. I am using FApacheFOP 2.1 of PDF generation. I am getting the image row at a from an API call then I am converting that image to base 64 format.

please find the java coe to convert image:

```
String jpgFileName = ConfigManager.getImageFilePath() + "/jpgImage-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
Blob imageDataBlob = (Blob) faesRow.get("imageData");

      FileUtil.writeToFile(imageDataBlob, jpgFileName);

      String base64Result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(FileUtil.readFromFile(jpgFileName).getBytes("utf-8"));

      result = base64Result;
```

I am using base64 type data in xslfo to print the image on PDF, Please find the xslfo below, here $!signatureImage is the data sent by the java code above:

```
<xsl:param name="Name">data:image/jpg;base64,{$!signatureImage}</xsl:param>

    <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" left="3.50in" top="9.25in" width="4.0in" height="2.0in">
      <fo:block text-align="left">
        <fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-to-fit"
            content-height="100%"
            width="100%"
            scaling="uniform"
            src="url({$Name})"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
```

In the output of template rendering I ma getting base64 stream there in the xslfo file. Please find the output below:

```
    <xsl:param name="Name">data:image/jpg;base64,{77+977+977+977+9ABBK... }</xsl:param>

<fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" left="3.50in" top="9.25in" width="4.0in" height="2.0in">
  <fo:block text-align="left">
    <fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-to-fit"
        content-height="100%"
        width="100%"
        scaling="uniform"
        src="url({$Name})"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Now the problem is that image is not getting priced at PDF output generated. **Can you please help me to find out a way to print Image here.**

Extra Information:
1. I am not getting any error to generate PDF.
2. PDF is able to print static images and barcode.

Comment: shouldn't the content type be `image/jpeg` instead of image/jpg ? Also, the  { } around the b64 string look suspicious to me.

Comment: I have tried with jpeg and by removing { } too.. But no luck, it is not showing the image. It is looking like problem is with base64 conversion, but not sure what is the issue.

Comment: when i do a base64 decode of your "base64" data 77+977+977+977+9ABB... it starts with 0xef 0xbf 0xbd 0xef ... which seems not to be a jpeg file which would start with 0xff 0xd8 and probably then 0xff 0xe0. looks wrong to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the problem in that case.

first issue was with base64 conversion, we need to use conversion as below:

```
 File file=  new File(jpgFileName);
 FileInputStream fileInputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
 byte[] b= new byte[(int) file.length()];

 fileInputStream.read(b);

 String base64Result = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(b),"UTF-8");
```

Other than this some change is also required in xslfo template too, Please find the change below:

```
  <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" left="3.50in" top="9.25in" width="4.0in" height="2.0in">
  <fo:block text-align="left">
    <fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-to-fit"
        content-height="100%"
        width="100%"
        scaling="uniform"
        src="url('data:image/jpeg;base64,$!signatureImage')"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Comment: The best questions on SO are those where the OP finds the answer himself.